# Is it possible to start a camel endpoint within process()

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

As the title says: is it possible to start a camel endpoint within the process function of the route(-builder)? I'm new to apache camel but already did some projects.

Situation as follows: 
I'm using apache camel in combination with Siemens Teamcenter RAC to execute a SavedQuery. The result is a ModelObject[] with the found elemtens.

For each of these elements I now need to start another endpoint executing a second search query. I thought about something like:

```
//within .process()
for (ModelObject ob : arrModelObjects) {
    // something like:  .to("direct:searchnew")
}
```

but i can't refer to outside-function ".to()" within the processor. Is there a workaround or solution or I am thinking the wrong way?

Comment: Take a look at ProducerTemplate

Comment: Or [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) if you need to do a second query and include the results in your ModelObject

Comment: a need to "send" each object to an endpoint, so I'm looking at the producer template first. Content enricher seems to be the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rathna mentions you can use the producerTemplate.

You can create a new producer template from you context which you can get form your exchange as follows:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor{

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();

    ModelObject[] arrModelObjects = (ModelObject[]) exchange.getIn().getBody();

    for (ModelObject ob : arrModelObjects) {
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:someEndpoint", ob);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
   class MyProcessor implements Processor{

    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         for (ModelObject ob : arrModelObjects) {
               producerTemplate.send("direct:searchnew",exchange);    
       }}
    }
```

Add producerTemplate to CamelContext.

Comment: add it as <camel:template id="producerTemplate"> in your configurations,where you have defined your route builders in the camel context

Comment: I'n not using camel context, i have an java main class in which I run the org.apache.camel.main.Main class